# Downloading Multiple Apps with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, ui-automation, automator

I would like to download all of the apps from an iTunes search result using AppleScript.

I only want to download the apps where they button says "Get" (I do not want to download paid apps or apps that have already been downloaded).

I have included a screenshot of the iTunes results and Accessibility Inspector below:

[image]

I have tried accessing the UI elements with the code below:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "iTunes"
    get buttons of UI elements of UI elements
end tell
```

Any recommendations would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a little sleuthing script to make life easier. For example, if you want to get the path to the first track under *Music* under *Playlist* column:

[image: Example]

where the "AXFrame" of field whose name begins with "Down to Earth" is `x=331.00, y=125.00 etc`. Find out its coordinate on screen with `Accessibility Inspector` and run this in `Script Editor`:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "iTunes" to set frontmost to true
    delay 1
    click at {331, 125}
end tell
```

In Results:

```
text field 1 of row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events"
```

Now you have the universal path to that element without navigating down layers of UI. Since you want to get to multiple elements, you need to be able to generalize, run loops, etc.

Comment: Because it is such a nice word, that "sleuthing", I had to look it up  to see what it means (I'm swiss-german):  "carry out a search or investigation in the manner of a detective" - ;)

Comment: @Zero etymology from OED: `Old Norse (and Icelandic) slóð (Norwegian slod, slo) track, trail.` :)

Comment: @Zero I caught a glimpse of ur last comment. It's a good idea expect Americans would go "Do u seriously want me to type letters with dialects?" (I'm American)

Comment: lol yes, sorry, I soon changed my opinion because I let NSSpeechSynthyesizer  say it out loud, using "Henrik" and "Nora" (Norwegian voices) and it kinda sounded not so good as I imagined lol